# fastcgi errors in log (ubuntu)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, fastcgi

I have this in my /var/log/apache2/error.log file :

```
[Thu Dec 20 16:10:37 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Dec 20 16:10:37 2012] [alert] (4)Interrupted system call: FastCGI: read() from pipe failed (0)
[Thu Dec 20 16:10:37 2012] [alert] (4)Interrupted system call: FastCGI: the PM is shutting down, Apache seems to have disappeared - bye
[Thu Dec 20 16:10:37 2012] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 854)
[Thu Dec 20 16:10:37 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.7.5 mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Any idea what this means?

Thanks,
Sammy

Answer (score 0):

The `alert` messages mean that the FactCGI process manager (PM) cannot talk to apache anymore and then quits.  If it cannot talk to apache, it will not be able to receive requests and sent answers back, so it's better it shuts down itself.

If this is happening when you actually restart apache, it's not too serious, because it's true that apache is not present anymore.  However, a graceful exit of the FastCGI PM should be better and should happen if it is configured correctly.

Are you restarting apache on your own for whatever reason (configuration change or anything) or are you restarting apache because the FastCGI processes are not responding anymore?